# How to sort a dataFrame in python pandas by two or more columns based on a list of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe with columns b. and c., I want to sort the dataframe by column b. in ascending order, and by column c. based on the order of a list, how do I do this?

Original df:

```
b.  c.
A   BA
A   PY
B   CH
A   CH
B   BA
C   BA
B   PY
C   PY
```

sort ascending for the "b." column and for "c." cloumn sort based on this list:

```
["PY","BA","MA","CH"]
```

so result should look something like this:

```
b.  c.
A   PY
A   BA
A   CH
B   PY
B   BA
B   CH
C   PY
C   CH
```

Comment: sorter = ["PY","BA","MA","CH"];
df['c.'] = df['c.'].astype("category");
df['c.'].cat.set_categories(sorter, inplace=True);
sorted_df = df.sort_values(['b.','c.'])

Comment: @DerekO this deserves to be the right answer for my question. dude thank you so much

Comment: Yeah I was about to post it before your question got closed! Glad to be of help anyway :)